# What is the meaning of the prompt "derpibooru_p_95", and what effect does it achieve?

Tags: prompt-design, stable-diffusion

When crafting a prompt for a generative AI image package - For example using Stable diffusion with the Automatic111 web ui - what is the meaning of the prompt fragment "derpibooru_p_95", and what effect does adding it to your prompt achieve?

Comment: This is a question about the meaning of the prompt, not the syntax. What does "derpibooru_p_95", mean, and what effect does it have on an image.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you: it's just a prompt. Have you tried running it through a tokeniser, like AUTOMATIC1111's 
stable-diffusion-webui-tokenizer extension? (You know what booru websites are, right?)

Comment: If you're not certain what this means, could you please not comment to say that you don't know. I don't want this to become that kind of thread.

Comment: [Derpibooru](https://www.derpibooru.org/) is a website that aggregates My Little Pony fan-art, sometimes with the artists' permission (though they're [reasonably good](https://www.derpibooru.org/dnp) about respecting explicit 'no's). Is that what you wanted to know, or are you asking about the `_p_95` part?

Comment: @wizzwizz4, It would be helpful. I can't find any reference to "_p_95" in the documentation for stable Diffusion. Is it the name of an artist?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that's referring to the 95th percentile of image score. (Likewise `derpibooru_p_low` would refer to low-ranked images.) I haven't any evidence of that, though: I can't find how Derpibooru art got into the Stable Diffusion datasets.

Comment: Where did you find this prompt? If it is from an image are you sure that image was created with the "normal" stable diffusion model and not one of the countless other models? This prompt fragment could have all kinds of effects depending on the actual model it is used with.

Comment: @Turamarth, it was on a set of available prompts on a LORA model that dealt with animals and anthros.